# Address coding in asynchronous FIFO

Tags: fifo

To generate FULL/EMPTY for FIFO control, the reading address/writing address needs to be transferred to the writing/reading side for comparison. A solution is to use gray code for the address to be safely delivered to the different clock domain because of only one bit will be flipped at a time. This is good if the depth of the FIFO D=2^K because only one bit changes for the transition from D-1 to 0. But what if D!=2^K, e.g., 13? The gray code is 1010 whereas the next address is 0000, for which 2 bits will be changed, and the 2-stage synchronizer is unsafe for such change. How is this problem solved for FIFOs with arbitrary depth? Will more complicated synchronization schemes be used? If yes, it seems converting from/to gray code is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical size of the RAM used inside the FIFO must be a power of 2 for the gray code scheme to work. The maximum depth of the FIFO as seen by external logic can still be limited to something less than 2<sup>N</sup>, but the actual read and write address counters will run through the full range of 0 through 2<sup>N</sup> - 1.